# How is Eobard Thawne still alive?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

I am still trying to figure out how Eobard Thawne is still alive. As seen in season one of *The Flash*,

> Eddie kills himself

to stop Thawne from going back to his time. But how does Eobard Thawne come back?

Answer (score 5):

Eobard Thawne is never really still "alive" after

> Eddie kills himself

What we have after season one is a [Time remnant](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Time_remnant). If Eobard is never born, there is no reason for Eddie to kill himself. If Eddie doesn't kill himself, Eobard will be born. It is a paradox. To prevent that, Eobard will continue to exist until the point where Eddie kills himself.